# How to update model parameters along with batch norm with accumulated gradients?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, similar to this question: [How to update model parameters with accumulated gradients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156957/how-to-update-model-parameters-with-accumulated-gradients)

I have a large network, and a very small batch size. To combat this I want to accumulate gradients (multiple forward passes) and then apply the update of the parameters using the mean gradient.

However, my network has BN layers. How should I handle this?