# TensorFlow: Removing nans in accumulated gradients

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

For a function approximation problem I'm trying to accumulate gradients but I find that sometimes some of these gradients are nan(i.e. undefined) even though the loss is always real. I think this might be due to numerical instabilities and I'm basically looking for a simple method for removing the nans from the computed gradients.

Starting with the [solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772685/how-to-accumulate-gradients-in-tensorflow) I tried doing the following:

```
# Optimizer definition - nothing different from any classical example
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()

## Retrieve all trainable variables you defined in your graph
tvs = tf.trainable_variables()
## Creation of a list of variables with the same shape as the trainable ones
# initialized with 0s
accum_vars = [tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(tv.initialized_value()), trainable=False) for tv in tvs]
zero_ops = [tv.assign(tf.zeros_like(tv)) for tv in accum_vars]

## Calls the compute_gradients function of the optimizer to obtain... the list of gradients
gvs_ = opt.compute_gradients(rmse, tvs)

gvs =tf.where(tf.is_nan(gvs_), tf.zeros_like(gvs_), gvs_)

## Adds to each element from the list you initialized earlier with zeros its gradient (works because accum_vars and gvs are in the same order)
accum_ops = [accum_vars[i].assign_add(gv[0]) for i, gv in enumerate(gvs)]

## Define the training step (part with variable value update)
train_step = opt.apply_gradients([(accum_vars[i], gv[1]) for i, gv in enumerate(gvs)])
```

So basically, the key idea is this line:

```
gvs =tf.where(tf.is_nan(gvs_), tf.zeros_like(gvs_), gvs_)
```

But when I apply this idea I obtain the following error:

> ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error:
>   Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 30 and 9. Shapes are
>   [2,30] and [2,9].     From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for
>   'IsNan/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [2,9,30], [2,30,9],
>   [2,30], [2,9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compute_gradients` returns a list of tensors in your case. You may want to do:

```
gvs_ = [(tf.where(tf.is_nan(grad), tf.zeros_like(grad), grad), val) for grad,val in gvs_]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and looks like this solved my problem too. Can you please explain this fix ? Also can you please tell if this has any impact on the final optimisation? Thanks

Comment: Basically all nan's are mapped to zeros. You should avoid nans, need to check why its happening at the first place.

Comment: Yes I get what you do here but is it theoretically correct to do that? The nans are getting generated in the `compute_gradients` function. To find the exact reason,  I will have to dig down to this function right?

Comment: This works, but is somewhat problematic as TF will unroll this is the graph. So if the number of variables for which gradients are computed is large, this will spam the graph.