# Why is training loss oscilating up and down?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, efficientnet

I am using the TF2 research object detection API with the pre-trained EfficientDet D3 model from the TF2 model zoo. During training on my own dataset I notice that the total loss is jumping up and down - for example from 0.5 to 2.0 a few steps later, and then back to 0.75:

[image: Tensorboard]

So all in all this training does not seem to be very stable. I thought the problem might be the learning rate, but as you can see in the charts above, I set the LR to decay during the training, it goes down to a really small value of 1e-15, so I don't see how this can be the problem (at least in the 2nd half of the training).

[image: Tensorboard smoothed]

Also when I smooth the curves in Tensorboard, as in the 2nd image above, one can see the total loss going down, so the direction is correct, even though it's still on quite a high value. I would be interested why I can't achieve better results with my training set, but I guess that is another question. First I would be really interested why the total loss is going up and down so much the whole training. Any ideas?

PS: The `pipeline.config` file for my training [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/haimat/9a373f7b021bbfd6c69c3e8134fce27c).

Comment: Which kind of object are u detecting  ?

Comment: It's three different kinds of plants, we have about ~20k training photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config it states that your batch size is 2. This is tiny and will cause a very volatile loss.

Try increasing your batch size substantially; try a value of `256` or `512`. If you are constrained by memory, try increasing it via gradient accumulation.

---

Gradient accumulation is the process of synthesising a larger batch by combining the backwards passes from smaller mini-batches. You would run multiple backwards passes before updating the model's parameters.

Typically, a training loop would like this (I'm using pytorch-like syntax for illustrative purposes):

```
for model_inputs, truths in iter_batches():
    predictions = model(model_inputs)
    loss = get_loss(predictions, truths)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

With gradient accumulation, you'll put several batches through and then update the model. This simulates a larger batch size without requiring the memory to actually put a large batch size through all at once:

```
accumulations = 10

for i, (model_inputs, truths) in enumerate(iter_batches()):
    predictions = model(model_inputs)
    loss = get_loss(predictions, truths)
    loss.backward()
    if (i - 1) % accumulations == 0:
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

**Reading**

- https://medium.com/huggingface/training-larger-batches-practical-tips-on-1-gpu-multi-gpu-distributed-setups-ec88c3e51255
- [How to accumulate gradients in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772685/how-to-accumulate-gradients-in-tensorflow)
- https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-use-gradient-accumulation-in-keras-models-fa02c0342b60
- [Understanding accumulated gradients in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067400/understanding-accumulated-gradients-in-pytorch)

Comment: I am indeed constrained by memory,- can you please elaborate on the "gradient accumulation"?

Comment: I added some information on gradient accumulation and reference reading.